# How to find the index of a given item in a list in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, contains

I have a list

```
In [1]:list=['AM','PM','MT']
```

and i have a df like this

```
In [1]:d= {'Date': ['8/10/2021','8/10/2021','8/11/2021','8/11/2021','8/11/2021','8/11/2021','8/11/2021'],
    'Name': [ 'John','Jason','Derek','Folley','Jason','Derek J','Derek M'],
    'Notes':['John was here 8:00:00 PM,before evryone','Jason did not come','He was here 9:00 PM,but he was sick','3:00 PM','Jason was here later 2000 MT','Derek J came at 10:00 PM, atleast he came','No Show'
]}
In [2]:df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = ['Date', 'Name','Notes'])

Out[1]:
  Date      Name    Notes
8/10/2021   John    John was here 8:00:00 PM,before evryone
8/10/2021   Jason   Jason did not come
8/11/2021   Derek   He was here 9:00 PM,but he was sick
8/11/2021   Folley  3:00 PM
8/11/2021   Jason   Jason was here later 2000 MT
8/11/2021   Derek J Derek J came at 10:00 PM, atleast he came
8/11/2021   Derek M No Show
```

I want to extract the the time out of the Notes section.
What I have done so far is as follows:

```
In [1]:Bool1 = df.iloc[:, 2].str.contains(r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(list)))
In [2]:df['Yes?'] =Bool1
Out[1]:
Date        Name    Yes?    Notes
8/10/2021   John    TRUE    John was here 8:00:00 PM,before evryone
8/10/2021   Jason   FALSE   Jason did not come
8/11/2021   Derek   TRUE    He was here 9:00 PM,but he was sick
8/11/2021   Folley  TRUE    3:00 PM
8/11/2021   Jason   TRUE    Jason was here later 2000 MT
8/11/2021   Derek J TRUE    Derek J came at 10:00 PM, atleast he came
8/11/2021   Derek M FALSE   No Show
```

What i would like is to find the index of the characters in the list when they show up ion the column of the df and then return the 9 characters to the left of it.
I do not know how to find the index of the item in list in the column in the df.

Desired Output:

```
Out[1]:
Date       Name     Yes?        Time            Notes
8/10/2021   John    TRUE    8:00:00 PM  John was here 8:00:00 PM,before evryone
8/10/2021   Jason   FALSE               Jason did not come
8/11/2021   Derek   TRUE    9:00 PM     He was here 9:00 PM,but he was sick
8/11/2021   Folley  TRUE    3:00 PM     3:00 PM
8/11/2021   Jason   TRUE    2000 MT     Jason was here later 2000 MT
8/11/2021   Derek J TRUE    10:00 PM    Derek J came at 10:00 PM, atleast he came
8/11/2021   Derek M FALSE               No Show
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try via `str.extract()`:

```
df['time']=df['Notes'].str.extract(r"([\d:]+\s*[AM|PM|MT]+)",expand=False)
```

Comment: This is great thank you ,Can i ask you an additional question, if there was a mixtures of numbers and strings and i wanted to extract the first 20 characters to the left of the "List"-[AM,PM.MT]. for example i have - "The total thing is 234 gamer AMSTRONG AM good here".I want to extract "234 gamer AMSTRONG AM" which includes the "AM": from the list in the end. How could i do that. Please help. Thanks

Comment: @Gamerarms sorry sir I don't know about this since I am learning regex and your initial  question was about extracting time so If you wish then I will delete this answer or you can ask another question regarding this with regex tag and close this question so kindly tell what you want to do!!